# How to get data of a clickable cell from a table that is dynamically populated

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table that is populated dynamically. I need to get data of a cell on clicking it .How can that be done.

I am populating the table in following manner :-

```
 function fetchAllRecords() {
    $('#tab_logic').empty();
    var html="";
    html+="<thead> <tr>  <th scope='col'>Order Id</th> <th scope='col'>Latitude/Longitude</th> <th scope='col'>OTP</th> <th scope='col'>Call Status</th> <th scope='col'>Call Duration</th> <th scope='col'>Call Unit</th> </tr> </thead> <tbody> ";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
      html+="<tr> <td onclick='tableFunction()'> <p id='trow"+i+"'> Data</p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td></tr>"
    }
    html+="</tbody>";
    $('#tab_logic').append(html);

    }
```

I tried getting the data like this but it didn't work

```
function tableFunction(){
    var txt = $(this).text();
    alert(txt);

    }
```

Comment: I think using in-line javascript is not a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `this` as an argument to the function.

```
      html+="<tr> <td onclick='tableFunction(this)'> <p id='trow"+i+"'> Data</p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td> <td> <p> Data </p></td></tr>"
```

and then use a function parameter

```
function tableFunction(element) {
    var txt = element.innerText;
    alert(txt);
}
```

But instead of using inline JavaScript, I recommend you use event delegation in jQuery. See [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved by  using .On() for selecting dynamically created rows.

```
$(document).on('click','td',function() {
 alert($(this).text());
});
```

I would suggest instead of directly targeting the `td`, adding separate class for the dynamically created `td` and calling them by this class name will be better.